# Repeating the line of numpy array mul

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have created an array
MyArray which looks like this, ***"array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.])"***
How do duplicate this line of array same time as the length of MyArray i.e. len(MyArray).
Thanks
Shei

Comment: You you want a 1 dimensional array that is len(MyArray)*len(MyArray) entries long, or do you want a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: 2Dimensional please

Answer (score 0):

This shows both ways.

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> np.tile(x,len(x))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> np.tile(x,(len(x),1))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>>
```

Comment: `y = np.empty([x.size, x.size], dtype=x.dtype); y[:] = x[:]` is the fastest method for this.